# Fixing matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib I like to customize my plots by shifting the spines from the origin, for example:

```
plot(range(10), marker='o', ms=20)

#customize axes
axes = gca()
axes.spines['right'].set_color('none')
axes.spines['top'].set_color('none')
axes.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
axes.spines['bottom'].set_position(('axes', -0.05))
axes.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
axes.spines['left'].set_position(('axes', -0.05))
axes.tick_params(axis='x', direction='out')
axes.tick_params(axis='y', direction='out')
```

[image]

#### **Question**:

What can I do to avoid my markers being cut at the borders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to turn off clipping by adding `clip_on=False` to your plot command:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10), marker='o', ms=20, clip_on=False)

axes = plt.gca()
axes.spines['right'].set_color('none')
axes.spines['top'].set_color('none')
axes.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
axes.spines['bottom'].set_position(('axes', -0.05))
axes.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
axes.spines['left'].set_position(('axes', -0.05))
axes.tick_params(axis='x', direction='out')
axes.tick_params(axis='y', direction='out')

plt.show()
```

which produces:
[image: result picture]

Comment: That's neat. What is the difference between that and `set_smart_bounds` in the other answer?

Comment: I don't know what `set_smart_bounds` does :-|

Comment: any idea, why the line is gone?

Comment: Ohh, thats my plotting style. I'll change it.

Comment: I think it is something else, I tried it and is the same here.

Comment: What did you do? I can't get it back.

Comment: `marker='o-'` does not make much sense, since the dash indicates a linestyle.

Comment: Previously I had `plt.plot(range(10), 'o')`, which removes the line completely. I now write `plt.plot(range(10), marker='o')`, which leaves the line intact and just adds the marker.

Answer (score 4):

```
from pylab import *
plot(range(10), marker='o', ms=20)

#customize axes
axes = gca()

axes.spines['right'].set_color('none')
axes.spines['top'].set_color('none')
axes.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
axes.spines['bottom'].set_position(('axes', -0.05))
axes.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
axes.spines['left'].set_position(('axes', -0.05))
axes.tick_params(axis='x', direction='out')
axes.tick_params(axis='y', direction='out')
axes.spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
axes.spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
axes.set_xlim(-0.5, 9.5)
axes.set_ylim(-0.5, 9.5)
axes.set_xticks(range(10))
axes.set_yticks(range(10))
```

[image]

Comment: well that interferes with my nice spines see [here](http://i.imgur.com/BHnIsaL.png)

Comment: @elyase The only difference I see is the ticks. You can set the ticks using `axes.set_xticks(range(10))`, and same for the y axis. That should give you the same result.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't, see [here](http://i.imgur.com/q3FL6Ct.png). The ends are not quite right.

Comment: @elyase So you wan't the axes to be from 0 to 9 and full circles... I updated the example.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez This looks good now, too bad it accumulated a couple of downvotes before. I hope you don't mind, I added the picture inline to help your post.

Comment: @Hooked yup, thanks :) I really don't know why the downvotes, I was trying to understand what the OP wants... :/

Comment: @ViktorKerkez, one of them was temporarily mine, now you got it back,;-)

Comment: There are now downvotes anymore, but your solution is arguably more complicated then mine :)

Comment: @DavidZwicker yes, I eliminated that one since I thought the OP doesn't want the circles to touch the spines.

Comment: both answers are good, I had to choose one, in any case I think both received a fair number of upvotes.